# How to spilt Fullname to First name, middlename and lastname in Query Builder?

Tags: sql, laravel, query-builder

I have a table and there is a "name" field, but sometimes there are names that are too long, how do I just take the first name, middle name and last name (only 3 words)?

```
$student = DB::table('student')
    ->select('student.name')//Split to Firstname, Middlename&Lastname
    ->get();
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, including data representing all edge cases (e.g. do some student names have only first and last, or maybe even just last).  Without seeing your data, we can't give you an answer.

Comment: Perhaps, you can read about [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators) It's a good way to do what you want do to.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think eloquent can do this. You need to use php builtin functions

```
$fullname = explode(" ", $student);
$firstname = array_shift($split);
$lastname  = implode(" ", $split);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Simpliest Way I think. Hope will help you

For me, it's a bad idea of splitting one word(fullname) into three, because what if, there are two words in his firstname, so the problem will exist as you are wishing only three words(first,middle,&lastname).

But if you really want to pursue, here's the code for that:

```
$student = DB::table('student')
    ->select(
        'student.name',
        DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(student.name, ' ', 1) AS Firstname"),
        DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(student.name, ' ', 2),' ',-1) AS Middlename"),
        DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(student.name, ' ', 3),' ',-1) AS Lastname")
    )
    ->get();
```

I assume you use or it is space(' ') that joins three words (first,middle, & last name)

**Note examples outputs:**
1. John Ghost Pon 
**Firstname** = "John", **Middlename** = "Ghost", **Lastname** = "Pon"
2. Marry Anne Smith Ingram
**Firstname** = "Marry", **Middlename** = "Anne", **Lastname** = "Smith"

---

**[SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring_index.asp)** Function returns a substring of a string before a specified number of delimiter occurs: [More examples](https://coderwall.com/p/zzgo-w/splitting-strings-with-mysql)

---

Please let me know if still doesn't work.